# How to read your own image data as a tensor in Tensorflow?

Tags: tensorflow

How do you read a bunch of images in tensor flow , specificly , I want my data to be read in the format : 
 tensor with shape [None, h, w, 3]. Where h and w can have arbitrary size.
I am unable to lead the data and read it as a tensor for multiple images.

Answer (score 0):

You can use python libs like [pickle](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pickle.html) to transfer you image to binary.

By the way, it will be more efficiency to do a preprocess before you train your model. This means you can transfer your image to binary, when training your model, just read the binaries you got.